# It there a way in powershell to make a positive number to a negative number whitout using multiplication?

Tags: powershell, negative-number

I was wondering if there is a way to make a positive number into a negative number whitout using a multiplication like `$b = $a * -1`
I'm looking for the most cost sensible way because I'm gonna do this a lot of times in a script.

-edit
At this point I'm using this, but lookes very costly computation wise:

```
    $temp_array = New-Object 'object[,]' $this.row,$this.col

    for ($i=0;$i -le $this.row -1 ; $i++) {
        for ($j=0;$j -le $this.col -1 ; $j++) {
            $digit = $this.data[$i,$j] * -1
            $temp_array[$i,$j] = 1 / ( 1 + [math]::exp( $digit ) )
            #[math]::Round( $digit ,3)
        }
    }
    $this.data = $temp_array
```

Comment: A couple of ways come to mind, by what do you mean by "cost sensible", and why can't you use multiplication?

Comment: $a = -1; $a = [math]::abs($a)

Comment: can u list a example of input you are using. Like what would $This.row be like and $this,col?

Comment: $this.row and $this.col wil be the boundery's of a matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To unconditionally turn a positive number into its negative equivalent (or, more generally, flip a number's sign), simply **use the unary `-` operator**:

```bash
 PS> $v = 10; -$v
 -10
```

Applied to your case:

```bash
 $digit = -$this.data[$i,$j]
```

---

As an aside: If performance matters, you can **speed up your loops by using `..`, the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-)** to create the indices to iterate over:

```bash
$temp_array = New-Object 'object[,]' $this.row,$this.col

for ($i in 0..($this.row-1)) {
    for ($j in 0..($this.col-1)) {
        $digit = - $this.data[$i,$j]
        $temp_array[$i,$j] = 1 / ( 1 + [math]::exp( $digit ) )
    }
}
$this.data = $temp_array
```